# What am I missing to make a grid of squares?

Tags: java

Create a program that will generate a grid set of boxes given the number of rows and columns.
Sample Input:
row = 3 and column = 4

Sample Output:

```
 -  -  -  -  
| || || || |
 -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  - 
| || || || |
 -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  - 
| || || || |
 -  -  -  -
```

I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
  static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
  static int row = 0; 
  static int col = 0;

  String[] square = { " -" + //"\n" + "| |" + //"\n" + " -" //"\n" };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewClass nc = new NewClass();

    System.out.println("row:"); 
    row = in.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("column:"); 
    col = in.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) { 
      nc.column(col); 
      System.out.println(); 
    }
  }

  public void column(int col) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) { 
      System.out.print(square[0]); 
    } 
  }
}
```

However The output is not correct. What am I missing?

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: I can't get the output right. Every time I use \n there would be no column only rows. if I don't use \n I have the column and the row but the output would be -| |-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with two nested forloops. The inner forloop prints the columns and the out forloop prints a newline to start a new row.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int row = 0, col = 0; 
    System.out.println("row:"); row = in.nextInt(); System.out.print("column:"); col = in.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) { 
            System.out.print(" - ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");     
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) { 
            System.out.print("| |");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");     
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) { 
            System.out.print(" - ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");     
    }
}
```

input: rows=3 cols=4

output:

```
 -  -  -  - 
| || || || |
 -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  - 
| || || || |
 -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  - 
| || || || |
 -  -  -  -
```

Comment: This doesn't print hyphens

Comment: the output should be like a digital zero.

Comment: see the edits i have made

Comment: yep, removed my -ve vote...

Comment: This one's right. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You may like to move the cursor to the position of the next square in the drawing order.
this way you'll have a square class that can draw itself and a controlling logic to place the cursor before each call to square draw method.